# Nest query to display records with [memCount] > 2?

Tags: sql

I'm working on creating a Script in SEQUEL ViewPoint. On the script, I have 3 lines that execute various Views to filter out data. Then, the last line displays data results using a Temporary Table which other views have inserted into on previous lines of the script.

The last line of my Script is something akin to:

```
DISPLAY SQL('SELECT sys, COUNT(memno) as memCount, Memno, userName, address FROM QTEMP/addrchg2 GROUP BY memno, sys, userName, address ORDER BY sys')
```

What I'm trying to do though is only display records where [memCount] is greater than 2. When I tried putting the lines `WHERE memCount > 2` after `FROM QTEMP/addrchg2` I received:

```
Escape: Query definition template 1 not valid.
Diagnostic: Field MEMCOUNT specified in WHERE clause not valid.
Escape: Query not created due to errors in specification.
An error occurred while running the command on line 4.
```

How best might I modify the last line of my script to display only those records with a `[memCount]` greater than 2?

**EDIT:**

```
DISPLAY SQL('SELECT sys, COUNT(memno) as memCount, Memno, userName, address FROM QTEMP/addrchg2 GROUP BY memno, sys, userName, address HAVING COUNT(memno) > 2 ORDER BY sys')
```

I'm now getting results. Going through and verifying if they are correctly what I'm after.

Comment: alias names cant be referred in WHERE clause this way, you need a _having count(memno) > 2_ after group by clause.

Comment: Ah, that explains it :S Any suggestions for a solution to what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DISPLAY SQL('SELECT sys, COUNT(memno) as memCount, Memno, userName, address FROM QTEMP/addrchg2 GROUP BY memno, sys, userName, address HAVING COUNT(memno)>2 ORDER BY sys')
```

Alias names, cant be used this way. i guess `HAVING` is what you look for.

i have added `HAVING COUNT(memno)>2` to your query.

Comment: Ok, that didn't error out like before, but now I receive: `Completion: Ownership of object SYMTAB in QTEMP type *USRSPC changed.
Completion: Ownership of object PARSEINFO in QTEMP type *USRSPC changed.
Diagnostic: Grouping function is not valid in WHERE clause.
Escape: Query not created due to errors in specification.
An error occurred while running the command on line 4.`...?

Comment: Updated, thanks! I'm getting results, checking if it's fully what I'm after :)